# For what reasons kubectl get pods fail

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Iam plunging into kubernetes to check it's status I run kubectl get pods command then iam getting error

For what reasons kubect get pods fail?

Getting error :The connection to the server xxxxxxxxx:6443 was refused-did you specify the right host or port?

How to fix this error?

Comment: Kindly ensure the details in “~/.kube/config” is proper.  If you don’t want to maintain in that path this can set using kubecontext.  More details are in https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The connection to the server xxxxxxxxx:6443 was refused-did you
specify the right host or port?**

As explained in this [doc](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/troubleshooting-kubectl-error-the-connection-to-the-server-x-x-x-x6443-was-refused-did-you-specify-the-right-host-or-port/) by Greek Diary ‘admin’ which clears up how to fix the kubectl error

> **Below troubleshooting steps will assist you  to resolve your issue**:
>
> 1.The kubectl should be executed on the Master Node.
>
> 2.Current user must have Kubernetes cluster configuration environment variable (Details of how to are listed under section Preparing to Use
> Kubernetes as a Regular User),
>
> ```
> $ env \| grep -i kube
>
>
>
> KUBECONFIG=/root/.kube/config
> ```
>
> 3.The docker service must be running:
>
> ```
> $ systemctl status docker
> ```
>
> 4.The kubelet service must be running:
>
> ```
> $ systemctl status kubelet
> ```
>
> 5.TCP port 6443 should be listed as it is listening to port:
>
> ```
> netstat -pnlt \| grep 6443
> ```
>
> If TCP port 6443 is not available, check firewall/iptables rules
> matching requirements: $ firewall-cmd --list-all
>
> Also check kubelet logs:
>
> ```
> # journalctl -xeu kubelet
> ```
>
> 6.Try restarting Kubernetes cluster which will also do some basic checks:
>
> ```
> $ [kubeadm-setup.sh](http://kubeadm-setup.sh) restart
> ```

**For what reasons do kubectl pods fail?**

Refer to this [doc](https://www.kukulinski.com/10-most-common-reasons-kubernetes-deployments-fail-part-1/)   by Ross Kukulinski for  more information about kubectl get pods fails

Comment: I wouldn't expect most users to be able to directly log in to a master node; you definitely shouldn't be doing work from there in normal operation.

Comment: I tried above solution. It's worked for me!